# How do I check a log file for a specific string length and call a downstream function in Python

Tags: python, logging

I have a *.txt log file that appends periodically with among other lines of data, a specific line of data, an example of which is in quotes below.

"15:04:46:093   8a4 ETH: GPU0 15.677 Mh/s, GPU1 27.137 Mh/s, GPU2 27.684 Mh/s, GPU3 29.166 Mh/s, GPU4 28.671 Mh/s, GPU5 25.741 Mh/s, GPU6 28.473 Mh/s, GPU7 28.596 Mh/s"

I want to create a python function that can interogate any and all files with name *_log.txt located in a directory called C:\Claymore ... for the most recent instance of a line in the format defined above, and to go on to call a downstream function in the event said line is less than 146 characters in length.

Does anyone have any idea where I could start with this?

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. For best result, i.e. getting a good answer, its best to provide what you have tried and what is not working. Take a read through [ask] for more information on how to properly ask. Specifically [example] is good to read

Comment: here are a few hints to start :
1. For finding all `*_log.txt` files, you could use [glob](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/glob.html)
2. For finding the lines, have a look at [re](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html). Regular expression seems the way to go if I understood correctly your problem.
3. For finding the most recent line, simply start at the end of the file and go towards the begging
4. Once you have your line a simple check (`if len(line) > 146`) should be enough

Comment: The complicated bit is in a log file with lots of different lines only some of which are in the format above, how do I pull out and distinguish the most recent entry or example that matches the format outlined above, and then go on to use the len(line) function you suggest?